# Curl in C Problem, very simple example returns an error [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'

Tags: c, curl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

 int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
   /*
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);


    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  */
  return 0; 
}
```

This is the code, I got it from the official website of CURL, I added the CURL Library normally into the MinGW (C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include), but when I try to run this example it returns this error

[Linker error] undefined reference to `*imp*_curl_easy_init'

if I take away the  line with: curl = curl_easy_init();
it works fine.

I'm Compiling with CodeBlocks with MinGW and Using Windows 7.

Thanks in advance

---

Another thing, is it necessary to compile the cURL library (or any other library) to use ? in my mind just having it included in the program like I'm doing

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

but I didn't compile the library and I don't even know if its necessary, only including it isn't enough ? what else is needed? if its necessary to compile, how to compile it ?

Thanks, I really need to learn to do this =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is not able to "link" with the library.

I'm sorry, I'm not particularly familiar with CodeBlocks, but here is what you need to do:
1) make sure that you downloaded the correct library (mingw32 version)

2) give the following options to the the compiler:

```
-lcurl -L"c:\libcurl\lib"
```

c:\libcurl\lib is the directory where libcurl.a is placed

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
The thing is I don't know where to put that option on the compiler. where should I look for to put it?

Comment: see the following two links from the Code::Blocks manual: http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-340001.11.13 and http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-650002.10 This should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to link with that CURL library. Secondly, *include* directories are meant for putting header files, not library files.

Comment: I was looking for and I saw something about use the mingw-make to compile the curl which I didn't do, but I don't know how to do that. can you explain me how to do that step by step? cause I've been days online looking for it, and I can't do, cause all the steps people give, they don't explain very much what they did. thank you!